"Extraordinary polarization" in a birefringent optical medium
In Nonlinear Optics by R. W. Boyd, I came across the following sentences about light polarization in an uniaxial birefringent medium:

Light polarized perpendicular to the plane containing the propagation vector $\mathbf{k}$ and the optic axis
is called the ordinary polarization. Such light experiences the ordinary refractive index $n_o$. Light polarized in the plane containing $\mathbf{k}$ and the optic axis is called the extraordinary polarization and experiences a refractive index $n_e(\theta)$ that depends on the angle $\theta$ between the optic axis and $\mathbf{k}$.

Is it assumed in the second sentence that polarization (direction of $\mathbf{E}$) is in the mentioned plane and perpendicular to $\mathbf{k}$? (Otherwise, it doesn't make sense to me that the refractive index of light polarized in the mentioned plane is independent of the angle between $\mathbf{E}$ and optic axis.) The Wikipedia article on birefrigerence shows that in an anisotropic medium
$\mathbf{E}$ is not in general orthogonal to $\mathbf{k}$. So the projection of $\mathbf{E}$ to the plane defined by optic axis and  $\mathbf{k}$ is not necessarily perpendicular to $\mathbf{k}$.


The above figure might be helpful.  It is from Chapter 14 of Born and Wolf, Principles of Optics (https://archive.org/details/principlesofopti00born/page/664/mode/1up).
The optic axis is $0Z$ and $\mathbf{s}$ is the wave normal direction.  The shaded region is called the principal plane.
The vector $\mathbf{D}'$ corresponding to the ordinary wave, with velocity independent of angle, vibrates at right angles to the principal plane.  The other vector $\mathbf{D}''$ corresponding to the extraordinary wave, with velocity dependent on angle, vibrates in the principal plane, but is also orthogonal to the wave normal direction $\mathbf{s}.$
However, as you point out, $\mathbf{E}$ is not necessarily orthogonal to $\mathbf{s}$ and furthermore, not parallel to $\mathbf{D}$ in a uniaxial crystal.
The relationship is given by:
$$
\mathbf{E}_{x}=\frac{1}{\epsilon_{1}}\mathbf{D}_{x}
$$
$$
\mathbf{E}_{y}=\frac{1}{\epsilon_{1}}\mathbf{D}_{y}
$$
$$
\mathbf{E}_{z}=\frac{1}{\epsilon_{2}}\mathbf{D}_{z}
$$
Note that the first two equations are related by the same factor $\frac{1}{\epsilon_{1}}$, but the third is related by $\frac{1}{\epsilon_{2}}.$  The factors $\epsilon_{1}, \epsilon_{2}$ are electric permittivity values for the crystal.
If one considers the $y$-axis to be along the $\mathbf{D}'$ direction, then $\mathbf{E}_{y}$ and $\mathbf{D}_{y}$ (and $\mathbf{D}'$) will be parallel.  On the other hand, since $\epsilon_{1} \ne \epsilon_{2}$ in the uniaxial crystal, $\mathbf{D}''$ will not be parallel in general to the component of $\mathbf{E}$ in the principal plane. Call it $\mathbf{E}''.$
For example, suppose $\mathbf{D}''=D_{1} \mathbf{x}+ D_{2} \mathbf{z}.$
Then we have
$$
E_{x}''=\frac{1}{\epsilon_{1}}D_{1}
$$
$$
E_{z}''=\frac{1}{\epsilon_{2}}D_{2}
$$
This shows that $\mathbf{E}''$ is not proportional to $\mathbf{D}''.$
If needed, please consult the Born and Wolf book referred above for further details.
